# Trying to send a mail using Mailgun API and its not working

Tags: python, python-requests, mailgun

For some reason i'm receiving a 200 status code on my MailGun Request but i'm not receiving any email. i checked the documentation multiple times and tried it multiple times but im still not receiving any mail. Please i'll appreciate assistance. Below is my code:

```
import requests

API_KEY = "*************************************************"
YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME= "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox*****************************.mailgun.org"

def send_simple_message():
        return requests.post(
            f"https://api.mailgun.net/v3/https://api.mailgun.net/v3/{YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME}/messages",
            auth=("api", API_KEY),
            data={"from": f"Excited User <mailgun@{YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME}",
                  "to": ["**************************@outlook.com"],
                  "subject": "Hello",
                  "text": "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!"})
```

Thank you

Comment: please login to your  mailgun dashboard to confirm if  your mail got there. If you got a 200 its probably there and if it didnt deliver, You will see the reasons there.

Comment: On my dashboard everything's still on 0

Comment: This detailed description may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68150905/can-i-send-email-with-mailgun-sandbox-domain-under-my-local-os/68542876#68542876

Answer (score 1):

If this is all your code, you might miss `send_simple_message()` after the definition.
It seems you built definition without calling it